# Return boolean value after a javaScript code is evaluated using javax.script.ScriptEngine object

Tags: java, javascript, javax.script

I am using javax.script.* package to evaluate javascript in a Java File. I am using a ScriptEngine object to evaluate some javaScript code. The javaScript code returns a Boolean value. I am not sure how to capture the boolean value in the Java file. For e.g., see:

```
import javax.script.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        String filepath = "../test.js";
        engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader(filepath));
    }
}
```

test.js

```
function test(value) {
    if(value==1) {
       println("True");
       return true;
    } else {
       println("False");
       return false;
    }
}

var i=1;
test (i);
```

I tried the following:

```
Boolean result = (Boolean) engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader(filepath));
```

The above line throws java.lang.NullPointerException error.

Thanks,
Sony

Comment: Did either of the `println`s work?

Comment: Yes, the println statements work fine. I edited the code in test.js.

Answer (score 1):

In JS:

```
var result=test (i);
```

In Java

```
engine.eval....
engine.get("result");
```